# event id : 5553 error, any solution please help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am getting the following error every one hour in SharePoint. Not sure what exactly is happening. Any help will be appreciated. The error is below.

> Event Id: 5553 failure trying to synch site
>   98f9c566-412c-49e3-b184-b22437447056 for ContentDB
>   362b1bf3-2234-417f-bf6c-7da5c9ad3444 WebApp
>   62a34660-7022-4a36-88a7-6813c8ad7788.  Exception message was Cannot
>   insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserMemberships' with unique
>   index 'CX_UserMemberships_RecordId_MemberGroupId_SID'. The duplicate
>   key value is (0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b, 123, 476,
>   0x0105000000000005150000001525af477973dd0607e53b2b9b190000). The
>   statement has been terminated..

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

This event occurs when the SharePoint Timer Job "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" fails. The "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" job runs every hour by default. The most common reason for this job to fail is inconsistent user profile data between the user profile service, and the content database. This inconsistency can occur when content databases are deleted or incorrectly moved.

**Resolution**

You can use stsadm command to list information about the databases that have not been synchronized with the user profile service.

```
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases n
stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases n
```

where 'n' is the number of days that have passed since the databases have been synchronized

The '-listolddatabases' command lists the content databases that have not been synchronized since 'n' days while the 'deleteolddatabases' command performs the same operation as the listolddatabases parameter, except it deletes old records corresponding to these databases. It does not delete the databases themselves. Once the synchronization references are deleted and a new profile synchronization occurs, new references will be stored in the database.

You must run the stsadm shell as the farm account for the previous commands to work successfully.

Source: [First hit in Google](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771190)

Comment: when i try to delete stsadm -o sync -deleteold databases. I am getting a error message saying                                                                                 A failure occurred during the processing of this command. Check diagnostic logs for more information

Comment: I could see that syncronization shows dated 3 years ago

Comment: What does the ULS log say when you run the -deleteolddatabases?

Comment: Clipboard reader could not understand a line. The line was: stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases n. Error was: System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at UlsGump.Column.TimeColumn.ParseTime(StringFacade timeString)
   at UlsGump.UlsEntry.SetEntryFromThread(StringFacade[] threadFacades, StringCacheFile stringCacheFile, Int64 messageLocation)

Comment: n must be integer, such as 0, e.g. stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0

Comment: this is what i see in ULS viewer as an error                               An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  Due to flags specified at object creation, this will not be freed until processed by garbage collection.  Allocation Id: {F7B175AF-0BD5-4360-A89D-0D48A0AB0283}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.

Comment: That error message is not related to the command, please try running it again, and pay close attention to ULS log.

Comment: i guess this error is due to stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0     the above error is shown in ULS when i do that and not because of deleteolddatabases.

Comment: my understanding is that when i use listolddatabases i see list of user profile service application out of which three of them are not been synchyronized that is the reason. Can you tell me how we can make sure it is getting synchronized